# How to add summary at top antd table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, antd

I can able to add the summary row at the end of the table. But I need to add it at the top. How can I do that in [**antd table**](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-summary)?

```
<Table
              columns={columns}
              dataSource={data}
              summary={pageData => {
                let totalWaste = 0;
                let totalBrick = 0;

                pageData.forEach(({ waste, brick }) => {
                  totalWaste += waste;
                  totalBrick += brick;
                });

                return (
                  <>
                    <thead>
                      <tr className="ant-table-row  ant-table-row-level-0">
                        <th>Summary</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>{totalWaste}</th>
                        <th>{totalBrick}</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                  </>
                );
              }}
            />
```

Comment: There is no props for this, handle it with css

Comment: Would you like to try use `components` property to override header renderer with you own implementation?

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani Can you show me pls

Comment: @Kyr Could you pls show me

Comment: before header or as a first row?

Comment: As a first row @FatemehQasemkhani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`summary` : is being added inside `tfoot` and there is no such option to make `summary` available as first row,

So Instead of using `summary`, we can make the same calculation and add one more `object` to own original data at first position.

**WORKING DEMO** :

[image: Edit Summary - Ant Design Demo]

---

**HACKED** : setting values inside header children to solve sorting issue

[image: Edit Summary - Ant Design Demo hacked]

Comment: The issue is when I do sort it takes it to the bottom again

Comment: @Profer, have added another demo please review that

Comment: @Profer, Gald to know, it helped. :)

Comment: @VivekDoshi, your first demo doesn't seem to work in the pagination. e.g. If total rows 110 and perPage is 100 (so total 2 pages), you will not be able to navigate next page. That's, you will see 100th row in the second page. Because datasource is 100 + 1 = 101. And I see antd warning: `dataSource` length is less than `pagination.total` but large than `pagination.pageSize`. Please make sure your config correct data with async mode.

Answer (score 2):

jsx：

```
<Table sticky  .../>
```

css:

```
.ant-table-summary {
      display: table-header-group;
}
```

Comment: Please consider explaining why this code might answer the question

Comment: Great, that is a simple way. `table-header-group` Make the element behave like a <thead> element

Comment: wonderful,It help me a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
<Table
  summary={() => <Table.Summary fixed="top">content</Table.Summary>}
  scroll={{ y: 500 }}
  ...
/>
```